# Inject an image with jQuery using Thymeleaf annotation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, datatables

I'm developing on a project that's use Thymeleaf.

I write this `<img th:src="@{/static/img/plusDetails.png}"></img>` into an html page. It works fine, the image is shown.

Now, I'm creating a table with dataTable plugin where I need to put an image into a column.

Fragment code of dataTable settings

```
"aoColumns": [
            {
               "mDataProp": null,
               "sClass": "control center",
               "sDefaultContent": '<img class="showDetails" th:src="@{/static/img/plusDetails.png}">'
            },
```

Not work.

This table is generated by jQuery at **runtime** (and I think it's just that the problem). 
jQuery inject the table in the same html page where the image is shown above.

So, `th:src="@{/static/img/plusDetails.png}"` it must be correct.

How can I solve?

Comment: 'Not work' isn't much to go on...  What HTML is rendered for the image?

Comment: Aye, I echo @markpsmith. What is the rendered HTML showing?